# Polymer 1.x and outer-element-click

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

So, I am designing a simple "log" element using Polymer 1.6 that displays a log message bellow whatever element I use it with.

It works fairly well, but, I would like to make the log message "disappear" if the user clicks anywhere on the page.

Which brings me to "outer-clicking" with Polymer 1.x

Most examples found on SE cover using existing events in Polymer modules, but I couldn't find anything that closely does what I'm looking for.

This example looked promising [Polymer: Detect click outside of custom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953906/polymer-detect-click-outside-of-custom-element) but, `Polymer.dom(target).node.domHost`is undefined in my tests...

So, anyone has any insight on how to catch the outer-click event ?

For the record, here is my-log element

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="my-log">
  <template>
  <style>
    :host {
      display: flex;
    }
  </style>
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    <span id="log" class="message"><content></content></span>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-log',
        extends: 'p',
        properties: {
          log: {
            type: String,
            observer: '_observeLogs'
          },
          logType: {
            type: String
          },
          logVisibility: {
            type: Boolean,
            value: false
          }
        },
        _observeLogs: function(val) {
          console.log('log changed to', val)
          if (val && val !== '')
            this.$.log.innerHTML = val;
        },
        _getLogClass: function(log, logType) {
          return logType !== undefined && logType !== false ? 'visible '+logType : '';
        }

      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no outer-click event. 
You can check if the `event.target` is inside or outside of a specific element. You can either iterate over parents and check if you reach `this` (inner) or `document` (outer) first.

You can also use [node.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) like

```
onClick(event) {
  var isOuter = !(event.target === this || this.contains(event.target) || this.root.contains(event.target));
  console.log('isOuter', isOuter);
}
```

I haven't tested `contains()` with Polymer myself yet.

Comment: It works indeed :D
I simply added it inside a click event attached to the window object, thank you !